# R could not find function "checkAtAssignment" while running rworldmap

Tags: r, rworldmap

I need your help with R not being able to run a function with rworldmap package.

When using rworldmap package in R and trying to 'joinCountryData2Map'

```
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map (myframe, joinCode = "NAME", nameJoinColumn = "location", verbose = TRUE, suggestForFailedCodes = TRUE )
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in mapWithData@data <- cbind(mapWithData@data, dF[matchPosnsInUserData,  : 
  could not find function "checkAtAssignment"
Calls: joinCountryData2Map
Execution halted
```

My guess is that R needs methods package, which I could not find for my R version.

Any suggestings why I 'could not find function "checkAtAssignment"'?

My R version is 3.0.2 Patched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using rworldmap package requires loading  library(methods). I am writing it here because it was really not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what  "R 3.0.2  Patched"  means, but yes you are correct that somehow you don't have the `methods` package, which is included in the standard installation package.  How about reinstalling `R` from the binaries or source tarball at CRAN -- that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Carl Witthoft. I can see 'methods' folder in R's library folder, so I should have it. I wanted to reinstall it from repo by doing <code>install.packages("methods", dependencies=TRUE)</code>, but got such reply: <code>Warning message:
package ‘methods’ is not available </code>. My default repo is <code>local({r <- getOption("repos"); r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.r-project.org"; options(repos=r)})</code>.... WTF?

Comment: @user3050366 since `methods` is in the standard install, it's probably not simple to install solo. What happens if you type `library(methods)` ?

Comment: I checked installed.packages, it returns methods "3.0.2". When I load methods, it loads.

Comment: ah dear... Me bad. I had to load it before executing my Rscript. library(methods) )))))